# Getting title of document in cefsharp browser

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I made a browser using cefsharp in winforms and I need to get the title of the page to put in the window  title. I haven't seen any way to get the title so far and have looked on google and have found nothing. Can anyone reply with how to get the title?

Comment: Does this work? This works in WPF, I'm not sure for winforms tho: `chromiumBrowserControl.Title`

Answer (score 3):

With CefSharp.WinForms v33.0.0 see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/BrowserForm.cs#L32

Comment: This lets you know when it changes, but it won't let you query it at any arbitrary time.

Comment: That is enough, at minimum, isn't it?  The title can be captured and recorded each time for random access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (sorry I tested it in VB) to store the current page title in `CurrentPageTitle` string:

```vb
AddHandler WebBrowser1.TitleChanged, AddressOf Browser_TitleChanged
Private Sub Browser_TitleChanged(sender As Object, e As CefSharp.TitleChangedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.TitleChanged
     CurrentPageTitle = e.Title
End Sub
```